# Confused with JavaScript asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript

Every tutorial repeats that JavaScript is synchronous, means that everything runs on a single thread, command after command.

Now, I'm super confused about async functions and Promises, how do they achieve the asynchronicity, if JavaScript is synchronous ?  How does JavaScript runs commands and detects events like mouse click ?

Lets say, we have some kind of API or a call to the database, how JavaScript knows when the data is ready for use ?

Comment: "running in a single thread" and "synchronous" are two orthogonal concepts

Comment: @Pointy Could you explain please ?

Comment: The terms _synchronous_ and _single threaded_ or often use in the wrong way. JavaScript runs single-threaded, so code of the same execution context (having access to the same objects/variables) won't run in parallel. The engine itself can be multi-threaded and do multiple tasks in the background. Synchronous and asynchronous describes whether you get the result (or the effect) of a function call immediately after the function returned, or if you get the actual result at a later point (that you get a Promise that resolves later, or that a callback function is called at a later pointer).

Comment: The relevant concept here in JS is the "event loop". You will find many explanations online if you Google it.

Comment: @t.niese That's what I'm asking, does a Promise runs on another side thread ?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Does the event loop runs in another thread than ? does I understand it right ?

Comment: @Wahalez no the Promise does not run in a separate thread.  The engine at some point provides an interface between the JavaScript context and the OS (like network communication, the reading/writing of files, …) and those parts that are outside of the JavaScript context can run in multiple threads, but the data/events will be passed back to the JavaScript context utilizing the event loop.

Comment: @Wahalez `[…]Does the event loop runs in another thread than ?[…]` no the event loop belongs to the JavaScript context and does not run in a separate thread. But other threads can push events into the queue of the event loop.

Comment: @t.niese So by your answer, I assume that there is a thread that listens to events mouse clicks and catches them and lists them to the event loop ? or I'm still confused ?

Comment: @Wahalez That would depend on one the implementation of the browser, but yes I would guess that it is done that way in case of mouse events too. (I'm not fully sure in case of mouse events, because you can cancel the default behavior of them, so those are a bit more complex than other events).